# Completely restart android app including application class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-manifest, navigation-architecture

I want to restart the application after the user changes language within the application.

- I'm starting new intent for `MainActivity` or as another solution I tried `activity.recreate()` methods but fragments are not initialized when restarting Activity. (I am using `Navigation Component`)
- I am using `Koin` for dependency injection and some scopes are lost and app crash.

I will restart the `Application class` and main activity specified in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, so how can I start the application as if I were reopening it from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This restarts the whole application

```
val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
context.startActivity(intent)
context.finish()
Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is correct and fixed my issue of restarting whole application